# How add image in html email template using windows application

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, winforms

**I am creating windows app in which i will be sending emailtemplate.htm file.**

**I want to know how can we load image in html template.**

> I have tried

1. Tried to add image using img src doesnt work.

**TestEmail.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome to GrassDew</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="border-top:3px solid #22BCE5">&nbsp;</div>
    <span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt">
        A new article has been published .<br /><br />
        <a style="color:#22BCE5" href="https://www.google.com/">NEw Article</a><br />
        <br /><br />
    </span>
    Thanks,<br />
    Team<br />
    <img src="../images/signature.png" /><br /><br />
</body>
</html>
```

> CS code :

```
        string strBody = string.Empty;
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string assemblyName = assembly.GetName().Name;
        string emailTemplateName = "TestEmail.htm";
        emailTemplateName = assemblyName + "." + emailTemplateName;
        //StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("oMail.Win.TestEmail.htm"));
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(emailTemplateName)))
        {
            strBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        strMsg.Body += "<span style = font-family:Calibri;font-size:14pt>Dear " + customrname + "</span><br/>" + strBody;
        strMsg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        System.Net.NetworkCredential smtpCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(strSMTPServerHostUserName, strSMTPServerHostPassword, strSMTPServerDomain);
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(strSMTPServerHost, Convert.ToInt32(strSMTPServerPort));
        smtpClient.Credentials = smtpCredential;
        smtpClient.Send(strMsg);
        bEmailSentSuccessful = true;
```

Comment: Please attach your code so we can debug it

Comment: attached code @OngaLeo-YodaVellem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `base64` string as a source of your image. It will be like a embedded image inside your `html`.

your `src` should look like

```
src="data:image/jpeg;base64, LzlqLzRBQ...<!-- base64 data -->"
```

For example:

```html
 Image Red Dot <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
    9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

You can find in google how to convert a image to base64 string. For example check this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/convert-an-image-to-base64-string-and-base64-string-to-image)

**Edit:**

When you are sending the html as email  `../images/signature.png` will not be resolved, either it should be a path to a server like "http://myserver/images/image.jpeg" or base64 string.

Comment: When you want to send email, it's always better to give a server url of the image or base64 string as source." ../images/" will not work when the email is received. Try encoding your image using https://www.base64-image.de/ and update your html. You will get the output.

Comment: tried adding base64 string as source. Is there another way?

Comment: give a complete path like http://myserver/images/image.jpeg. it can't be ../images . Note that when you type the path on browser you should get the image.